# Конструктор делегата

Tags: c#, конструктор, синтаксис, делегаты

Подскажите, пожалуйста, почему при объявлении делегата не нужно вызывать его конструктор с помощью ключевого слова new?

```
int TestF(int i){ return i*2-1}
delegate int TestDel(int i);
TestDel del = TestF;
```

Comment: Добавьте в вопрос то как вы объявляете и то, как вы считаете надо объявлять

Answer (score 2, accepted):

На самом деле надо.

Но, начиная с C# 2.0, для упрощения синтаксиса была добавлена возможность неявного преобразования, которое компилятор развернет самостоятельно, сравните IL-код и увидите что он идентичен: [пример](https://sharplab.io/#v2:C4LglgNgNAJiDUAfAAgJgATIIwHYCwAUAN6HpmYAs6AslgBQCUp5JB57NAnsgKzoCG6ALzoAdgFMA7l150AygEcATgwDczMgF8N6HcirVUjHaw7lq3PoJGKl6tuW0E9AZnQxxEcQHN+wcehgosAyPHRBIZxqhK6Bwei24fH8DMIAfALoAFQC9ppAA===)

В обоих случаях вызывается конструктор.